# What is the point of casting an instance to a certain type?

Tags: java, types

I am a bit confused on the purpose of declaring instances as specific types.  For example,

```
Integer intOb1 = new Integer(3);
Object intOb2 = new Integer(4);
```

I know the type of `intOb1` is `Integer`, and the type of `intOb2` is `Object`, but what does declaring `intOb2` as `Object` allow one to do?  Use methods in `Object`?  Can't you already use those methods as an `Integer`?  Or is the main purpose just to be able to "treat" `intOb2` as an Object?

As you can see, I'm befuddled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actual isn't called casting this is an example of *polymorphism*. Which allows variables to take on different types based on their inheritance relationships with other classes.

For example, suppose you were writing a program to simulate a zoo. You would have a class called `Zoo` and a class called `Animal`. There are also several classes that extend from the `Animal` class: `Lion`, `Zebra`, and `Elephant`.

It would be extremely useful to keep all of these objects grouped together in a single list but since they are of different types, i.e: `Lion`, `Zebra`, and `Elephant`, you can't store them in a single list, you would have to maintain a separate list for *each* type of animal. This is where polymorphism comes into play.

Since each of the classes `Lion`, `Zebra`, and `Elephant` all extend from the `Animal` class we can simply store them in a list of type `Animal`.

code example:

```
public class Zoo
{
   private List<Animal> animals; 

   public Zoo()
   {
      this.animals = new ArrayList<>();
   }

   //notice this method takes an Animal object as a parameter
   public void add(Animal a)
   {
      this.animals.add(a);
   }
}

public abstract class Animal
{
   private String name;
   private String type;

   public Animal(String name, String type)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.type = type;
   }

   //all subclasses must implement this method
   public abstract void speak();
}

public class Lion extends Animal
{
   private String animalType = "Lion";

   public Lion(String name)
   {
      super(name, animalType);
   }

   public void speak()
   {
      System.out.println("ROAR");
   }
}

//....etc for the other two animals

public class TestZoo
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Zoo myZoo  = new Zoo();
      Lion l     = new Lion("Larry");
      Elephant e = new Elephant("Eli");
      Zebra    z = new Zebra("Zayne");

      myZoo.add(l);  //<-- note that here I don't pass Animal objects to the 
      myZoo.add(e);  //    add method but subclasses of Animal
      myZoo.add(z);
   }
}
```

Hope this helps, even with a silly example.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but in the main method, if I instead wrote


      `Animal l     = new Lion("Larry");
      Animal e = new Elephant("Eli");
      Animal z = new Zebra("Zayne");`

What new functionality would that give?

Comment: @Hubrid The functionality that it gives you is you can store all of the objects in the same list or container even though they all have different types.

Comment: I know it is a valid way to create Animal objects, I'm just confused as to why `Animal l = new Lion("Larry");` would ever be preferred/not preferred over `Lion l = new Lion("Larry");`.

Comment: @Hubrid It can be useful because sometimes when you are writing a function you may not know what subclasses could be passed in as parameters. So if you make the list of the most generic type possible it will be able to hold all possible subclasses.

Comment: Okay- I see.  Thanks a ton for taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: Not to be too pedantic, but `Object o = new Integer(1)` *does* involve a cast -- an upcast, specifically, which is always valid and never needs to be explicit.

Comment: @yshavit Yes, _technically_ there is a cast, but one that is invisible to the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

When `Object` is involved you never get anything useful, since it's a generic type which doesn't help anywhere.

But think about a different situation:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This means something specific: `list` is an `ArrayList` and declaring it just the generic `List` collection enforces the fact that throughout the code you won't use any `ArrayList` specific method.

This effectively allows you to state that you won't rely on any specific implementation, you will later be allowed to switch `ArrayList<String>()` to, for example, `LinkedList<String>()` without having to modify anything else.

Comment: I think @Hunter's point is important; what the OP has done here isn't (explicit) casting at all.

Comment: I wasn't sure what exactly to call it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use method of the "Object" class from object of any type of class because all classes are subclasses of "Object"

Instead, you need to understand this why anyone create object of type class Object:

Type casting generally required when you want to write some method/functionality and you are not sure which type of object may come as input. One of the most common example in JDK is equals method or compare method in comparator.

```
// Object equals method - written for such generic use.
boolean     equals(Object obj) {
  //Here you might want to check which is other type of object.
  if (!obj instanceof CurrentClass) {
      return false;
  }
  //Additional logic required to check equality of object.
}
```

Similar case was also there for the Collection library earlier(JDK 1.4) but JDK 1.5 introduced new feature called generic.